# Where is the source tree in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Upon click on "tree", gitk shows the directory tree for a given commit.  Is there something similar in sourcetree?

### Example (gitk)

- Directory tree as of first revision (see lower right window frame)

  [image: Directory tree as of first revision]
- Directory tree as of second revision
  [image]

Comment: At first I was going to type "Just go to your Bookmarks window," but I realize that that isn't what you want. What do you want? Can you give us a screenshot or something? (I don't use gitk so I don't what you need...)

Comment: @paul For a given revision (aka commit) I'd like to see the directory structure of the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsing the source tree at any given revision is not available right now in SourceTree (v1.5.3).

A feature request has been submitted as [bug #1021](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1021) in JIRA (the official Atlassian bug tracker).

It hasn't been implemented yet but it's expected to be released in 1.6.

You can register to JIRA and up vote or watch the issue if you want.

Comment: These days I'm using mostly vanilla git for commits and [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) (from brew). When I want a better / different visualization of the tree I'm using either SourceTree or [GitX (the rowanj fork)](http://rowanj.github.io/gitx/).

Comment: Thanks for those. Now hopefully someone develops similar things for Windows as well (:

Comment: Version 1.9.9 and still waiting.

Comment: Version 4.1.5 and still waiting.

Answer (score 3):

Choose File Status tab (at bottom) > All files (at top) > Tree view.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean